# Java (Selenium) - super class constructor to initialise sub classes

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

`PageOne` and `PageTwo` both need to make use of `MasterPage` methods (eg click Ok). I'm trying to initialize both pages within the constructor of `MasterPage`.
IntelliJ tells me to either add super(driver) to the `Page1`/`Page2` constructors, or to add a no arg constructor to master. In both cases, the tests can't run. with a super(driver) constructor, the pages fail to initialize, and in the no arg constructor, the `clickOk()` method fails when called from the Page1/Page2 method.

**MasterPage:**

```
public class MasterPage {

    private WebDriver driver;
    public Page1 p1;
    public Page2 p2;

    public MasterPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        p1 = new Page1(driver);
        p2 = new Page2(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy(id = "OkBtn")
    private WebElement okBtn;

    public void clickOk() {
        okBtn.click();
    }
}
```

**Page1:**

```
public class Page1 extends MasterPage {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public Page1(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy(id="field")
    private WebElement elementOne;

    public void completePage() {
        elementOne.click();
        clickOk();
    }
}
```

**Page2:**

```
public class Page2 extends MasterPage {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public Page2(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy (id="field")
    private WebElement elementTwo;

    public void completePageTwo() {
        elementTwo.click();
        clickOk();
    }
}
```

My intention is to utilise them like this:

```
public class Page1Steps {

    MasterPage master;
    WebDriver driver;

    public void testMethod() {
        master = new MasterPage(driver);
        master.p1.completePage();
        master.p2.completePageTwo();
    }
}
```

You may be able to tell, I'm not 100% sure of the best way to approach this problem, so any guidance would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `MasterPage` shouldn't know about `page1` and `page2`, it's their base class. You also don't need `driver` in each one of the derived `Page`, you can hold it in the parent `MasterPage`.

The problem is `MasterPage` constructor receives `WebDriver` parameter, but you don't have call to `super(driver)` in the derived classes constructors.

I also suggest each method which navigates the test to the another page will return this new page

**MasterPage:**

```
public class MasterPage { // can be abstract

    protected WebDriver driver;

    public MasterPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy(id = "OkBtn")
    private WebElement okBtn;

    protected void clickOk() {
        okBtn.click();
    }
}
```

**Page1:**

```
public class Page1 extends MasterPage {

    public Page1(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    @FindBy(id="field")
    private WebElement elementOne;

    public Page2 completePageAndGoToPageTwo() {
        elementOne.click();
        clickOk();
        return new Page2(driver);
    }
}
```

**Page2:**

```
public class Page2 extends MasterPage {

    public Page2(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    @FindBy (id="field")
    private WebElement elementTwo;

    public void completePageTwo() {
        elementTwo.click();
        clickOk();
    }
}
```

**Page1Steps:**

```
public class Page1Steps {

    public void testMethod() {
        Page1 pageOne = new Page1(driver);
        pageOne
            .completePageAndGoToPageTwo()
            .completePageTwo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much that’s given me a lot to think about - still learning best practises. I’ll tidy up my code and implement what you’ve suggested. Cheers again.